# How to merge a set of small psd images into a printable A4?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I have a large set of different small images from the very same size (660 x 144 pixels, 120 pixels/centimiter) which I like to print in a A4 papaer.

Is there some automated script that fit those images and insert some "cutting guidelines"?

Comment: Hey RSFalcon7, could you expand as share with us what you've already tried yourself? Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider "a large set" of images, how many? Can you do some manual work after initial set up?

Comment: @Johannes I tried the manual way: create an A4 image and manually align every small image, when it fills the entire page, create another and so on

Comment: @ACEkin Right now I have 140 images, but the number might increase in a few days. Sure I can, right now my only method is only manual

Comment: OK, I will make some time to outline a process that will probably make it go at a good speed. I used to lay out about 900 tiny images on one sheet. Stay tuned.

Comment: @RSFalcon7, have you seen the step-by-step instructions I wrote a few days ago? Have you had a chance to try them? Did they work for you?

Comment: Hi @ACEkin . A friend of mine suggested a solution based on excel that didn't need all those images whatsoever, so I'm not doing anything manual anymore, sorry for you trouble. I will accept your your answer since it seems to produce the best results with the minimum amount of manual work so far. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Glad to hear you found the answer. The solution with Excel sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. All your items are the same size as you indicated
2. The orientation does not matter as you can rotate them on paper

Here is the process you may follow. The initial setup is a little exacting and time consuming but after that you can lay out the images very quickly on this template.

1. Start a blank document in A4 size
2. On a new blank layer, draw a rectangle EXACTLY 660x144 pixels and fill it in a solid color, say red or green
3. Press Ctrl-J twice to make two copies of this shape
4. Place the first rectangle on the top left corner of the usable space depending on your printer
5. Take the next layer and put it on the top right of the usable space in these two steps pay attention mainly to the outside edges on the left and right
6. Now select all these layers, go to "Layer/Align/Top edges". This will make the perfectly aligned
7. While the layers are selected, go to "Layer/Distribute/Horizontal Centers". Now you will have perfectly aligned and distributed rectangles.
8. While the layers are selected, draw guides that snap to the edges of the rectangles, these will become your main tool to place the actual images you have on the template
9. Select all the shape layers, press Ctrl-G to group them. Press Ctrl-J to duplicate the group
10. IMPORTANT, Press Alt-Ctrl-T to bring up the free transform tool (NOT JUST CTRL-T)
11. Hold the shift key down and drag the new layer group which is now surrounded by the free transform rectangle and drag it down a short distance so that the two lines of groups are slightly separated and press Enter
12. Press Ctrl-J to replicate this group, and IMPORTANT press Shift-Ctrl-T which will repeat the previous move.
13. Repeat step 12 enough number of times until you fill the page with a little room left at the bottom
14. Go back and draw guides that touch all the sides of all the shapes
15. After all the guides are in place, turn off the shape layers, now you have the white background and a lot of guides
16. Draw 1 pixel pencil lines on each guide on the background layer, these will become your cut lines
17. You can delete all the shape layers making sure that each space is now marked by guide lines
18. Save this document as your layout template
19. When you have the images you want to lay out ready, open the template, save it with a new name, drop as many of your images on the background and move them to line up with the guides.

I am adding a half way done template to show you what I mean, with and without the guidelines.

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to InDesign I would use that. In InDesign you can grab your frame tool (<kbd>F</kbd>) and drag out a a selection the size of your printable area. While still holding the mouse button, press the <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> arrow keys. It will automatically generate evenly spaced boxes as many times as you wish. Once you have the amount you think you may need hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>D</kbd> and select all the images/psd you want to import and then just click on the boxes and they will fill in as you click. You can add printer marks in the export options or if you want to do it individually for each image, you can set up a new style in the object styles!

Or, in Photoshop, you can go *File > Automate > Contact Sheet*. Browse / select images you want to use and it will generate contact sheets for you. No cut lines though.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have InDesign and the Contact Sheet's output was not not what I was expecting.